# notification.setLatestEventInfo not found

Tags: android

I am getting method not found in notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, TAG, message, contentIntent) method.
Do I have to change the build.grade?

```
private void displayNotificationMessage(String message) {
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.emo_im_winking,
            message, System.currentTimeMillis());

    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    PendingIntent contentIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, TAG, message, contentIntent);

    notificationMgr.notify(0, notification);
}
```

This is my current build.grade:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidbook.services.simplelocalservice"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setLatestEventInfo` was removed in API 23. Use a `Notification.Builder` instead.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Comment: I needed to used api 19. So I have to use "setLatestEventInfo". Not sure why I am still getting error method not found when I changed the gradle.build to 19.

Answer (score 1):

Use NotificationCompat instead.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

setLatestEventInfo has been deprecated for a long time.